# How to convert a csv format values inside a dict to JSON format in python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I know how to convert the csv file and extract the datas. But this is something different, I get the values from the database as in csv format and I need to convert for JSON format.

Current Output:

u{'content':'heading1,heading2,heading3'\nrowa1,rowa2,rowa3\nrowb1,rowb2,rowb3}

Expected to convert this in to proper JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Take this example

```
data = "heading1,heading2,heading3;rowa1,rowa2,rowa3;rowb1,rowb2,rowb3;"
lines = data.split(';')
headers = lines[0].split(',')
output = [{h: d for h,d in zip(headers,line.split(','))} for line in lines[1:-1]]
print(output)
```